# How to achieve tree view from JSON data using Angular 6

Tags: treeview, angular5, angular6, angular-material-5, checkboxtree

I want to design a checkbox tree structure using following data coming from Web API using Angular 6. How can I achieve it please help.

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "Fund_type":"A&P"   
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "Fund_type": "On Invoice"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "parent_id": 2,
    "Fund_type": "Banded packs-Consumer"
},
{
    "id": 4, 
    "parent_id": 2, 
    "Fund_type": "Banded packs-Shopper" 
},....]
```

Where id=1 is the root node and id=2 is the direct child of it and id=3 &4 are direct children of id=2(You can understand the structure from parent_id )

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your data as per the example given below and use this component:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-treeview

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use angular tree view in
https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-ui-components/angular-treeview